# Action Destroy redirect to Show Action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I am building a link to `delete`:
I tried 3 different forms but all of them redirect to `Show` action:

1. `<%= link_to 'delete',{ :controller => 'admin/brands',:action => 'destroy',:id => brand.id } %>`
2. `<%= link_to 'delete',brand,:method => :delete %>`
3. `<%= link_to 'delete',:id => brand.id,:method => :delete %>`

The problem is when I click the delete link it redirects to `Show` action. I have searched and found something like:

```
//= require jquery_ujs add in aplication.js - Correct !
```

metatags added in layout:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Correct!

I also found this option:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

I'm using `Development enviroment`(I think) and not found this option; therefore I don't know why when I click the delete link app redirects to action Show.

**UPDATE:**

My routes are:

```
DELETE /en/admin/pages/:id(.:format)  admin/pages#destroy {:locale=>"en"}
DELETE /admin/pages/:id(.:format)     admin/pages#destroy {:locale=>"pt-BR"}
```

When I click on any `Delete` link it redirects me to action `Show`

Comment: Do you want to redirect to show action after delete?

Comment: I read it two times, and understood nothing: what do you want, what is wrong and what it has to do with JS?

Comment: No, i dont redirect to show after delete, the wrong is when i click in the link to delete he redirect to show path

Comment: You need to add more information, how are you routes defined? What link is wrong? What its the real problem?

Comment: I try 3 times how i write but the respost is the same, the action redirect to Show, the route is normal whit delete.`                                    DELETE /en/admin/pages/:id(.:format)                           admin/pages#destroy {:locale=>"en"}
                                    DELETE /admin/pages/:id(.:format)                              admin/pages#destroy {:locale=>"pt-BR"}
`

Comment: Solve this executing `rake assets:clean`, thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this executing `rake assets:clean`, thanks all.